# drag and drop broken on vista

Tags: windows-vista, drag-and-drop

I recently updated to Vista SP2, and since then drag and drop (actually just drag, if I can't drag then can't drop either) (in windows explorer) has been intermittently broken.

Sometimes it works, and then a few minutes later it doesn't. It's not limited to any specific folder, all folders, desktop, etc have this problem.

I've turned UAC off...

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Edit:

Column (name, type, size, etc) resizing is broken too. But I can right click on the labels and do size columns to fit.

Comment: Have you tried a quick restart?

Comment: It's been happening for a few days now, so I've started a couple of times already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does "drag & drop" stop working after a while?](http://superuser.com/questions/29266/why-does-drag-drop-stop-working-after-a-while)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem look for "drag&drop" tag on Super User. The problem came from a little sift called TEXTER, are you using it too? Since I delete TEXTER everything works fine in my PC I ope it might help you.

Comment: The drag&drop tag was deleted as it does not meet the SU requirements. You will need to update this with a link to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug, but not necessarily in Windows.

It is caused by third party shell add-ons that get loaded at some point - not sure exactly when, I think it is when attempting draw a preview or extract meta data.

Typically this would happen just after I started dragging and "freeze" the process.

When this happened, I noticed that in task manager, there was a task called drag.exe which I could terminate. After this, it would work again until the next time.

Look in task manager for this (my memory is going, could of been drop.exe, but I am 99% sure it was drag), and if not, restart your machine. Try and remember what type of file it was that froze and then see if you installed any sort of program / handler for this type of file.